# Postgres - Distinct + jsonb_object_keys gives error set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying run the following query

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys("classif_ai_fileregion"."defects") AS "defect_ids" 
FROM "classif_ai_fileregion" 
WHERE 
("classif_ai_fileregion"."file_id" IN 
  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_file" U0 ) 
AND 
"classif_ai_fileregion"."ml_model_id" IN 
  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_mlmodel" U0 WHERE U0."id" IN (2)))
```

I get the following error

```
SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys("classif_ai_fileregion"."defects") AS "defect_ids" FROM "classif_ai_fileregion" 
WHERE 
("classif_ai_fileregion"."fi...

ERROR: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
  Position: 17

SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys("classif_ai_fileregion"."defects") AS "defect_ids" FROM "classif_ai_fileregion" 
                ^
```

Now, there are a few modified versions of the above query which I tried and all of them seems to work. From the above query, I replace `U0."id" IN (2)` with `U0."id" IN (1,2)` or `U0."id" IN (1)` and the query works. Or I remove `"classif_ai_fileregion"."file_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_file" U0 ) AND` and it works.

I'm unable to understand why it works with those modifications and why it won't on the original query.

To make it easier to understand the query, the following are the tables.

1. classif_ai_file

   - id
2. classif_ai_mlmodel

   - id
3. classif_ai_fileregion

   - id
   - file_id
   - ml_model_id
   - defects - jsonb type

defects column is of the form {1: {}, 2: {}}

**Note:** I am writing a few similar queries below this line which does some how work while the initial query in the question doesn't.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys("classif_ai_fileregion"."defects") AS "defect_ids" 
FROM "classif_ai_fileregion" 
WHERE 
("classif_ai_fileregion"."file_id" IN 
  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_file" U0 ) 
AND 
"classif_ai_fileregion"."ml_model_id" IN 
  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_mlmodel" U0 WHERE U0."id" IN (1)))
```

You can notice that I just changed 2 to 1 in this query.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys("classif_ai_fileregion"."defects") AS "defect_ids" 
FROM "classif_ai_fileregion" 
WHERE 
("classif_ai_fileregion"."file_id" IN 
  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_file" U0 ) 
AND 
"classif_ai_fileregion"."ml_model_id" IN 
  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_mlmodel" U0 WHERE U0."id" IN (1,2)))
```

You can notice that I just changed 2 to 1,2 in this query.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys("classif_ai_fileregion"."defects") AS "defect_ids" 
FROM "classif_ai_fileregion" 
WHERE  
"classif_ai_fileregion"."ml_model_id" IN 
  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_mlmodel" U0 WHERE U0."id" IN (2)))
```

I removed an extra where clause in this query.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys("classif_ai_fileregion"."defects") AS "defect_ids" 
FROM "classif_ai_fileregion" 
WHERE 
("classif_ai_fileregion"."file_id" IN 
  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_file" U0 ) 
AND 
"classif_ai_fileregion"."ml_model_id" IN 
   (2))
```

I just simplified the where clause for ml_model_id here

Comment: So is your question how to avoid the problem with the set returning function or why the ORM generated conditions aren't working correctly? Please only ask  a single question per question.

Comment: You can ignore the ORM thing completely. I want to understand what is causing this error in the query I have posted in the question. And why is it working for other similar queries which I posted in the bottom part of the question

Answer (score 0):

Move the function to the FROM clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT df.defect_id
FROM "classif_ai_fileregion" 
  cross join lateral jsonb_object_keys(classif_ai_fileregion.defects) AS df(defect_id)
WHERE ("classif_ai_fileregion"."file_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "classif_ai_file" U0 ) 
  AND "classif_ai_fileregion"."ml_model_id" IN (SELECT U0."id" 
                                                FROM "classif_ai_mlmodel" U0 
                                                WHERE U0."id" IN (2)))
```

Note that your second WHERE condition can be simplified to

```
AND "classif_ai_fileregion"."ml_model_id" IN (2)
```

Comment: I would try this way although since I'm using the Django ORM, it might be tricky to construct this query. Also, the condition in the last is not something I want to simplify as you said because there could be additional where clauses that might could be added. But can you help in understanding why it works for U0."id" IN (1) and not work for U0."id" IN (2)?

Comment: The joys of obfuscation layers...  But `where c1 in (SELECT some_column from other_table where some_column IN (x,y,z))` never makes sense. And is always equivalent to `where c1 in (x,y,z)`. There must be more going on if that only works for certain values in your database.

Comment: `where c1 in (SELECT some_column from other_table where some_column IN (x,y,z))`
Yes, This doesn't make sense but `where c1 in (SELECT some_column from other_table where some_column IN (x,y,z) and some_other_column IN (1,2,3))` does make sense. So, I use django ORM to chain more and more where conditions as required and I pasted the simplest query here. It's very confusing that it works for (1) and (1,2) but not for (2) alone. Also, Can you go through the similar cases which I mentioned in the question. I feel it's a very weird behaviour.

Comment: Well, if it works for (1,2) and (1) but not for (2) means that there is no row with id = 2

Comment: There are so many rows with both 1 and 2. I manually checked it. It works if I just remove the distinct keyword. Without applying distinct, the results are more than 8k records for id=2 and more than 40k records for id=1

Answer (score 0):

`jsonb_object_keys()` returns a set of records, meaning it returns multiple rows. This is not allowed in the `SELECT` list in that case.

Without knowing your data, I guess your changes filtered your data set in that way, that only one record remained. A set-returning function is allowed in the `SELECT` list if and only if returns not more than exact one record.

So, what you should try to do is, moving the function into the `FROM` list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    *
FROM "classif_ai_fileregion",
    jsonb_object_keys("classif_ai_fileregion"."defects") AS "defect_ids"  
WHERE ...
```

The comma creates an `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` which says, that the function is called for every records separately which should yield the same as your original expected output.

Comment: Set returning functions are allowed in the SELECT list in certain cases. However I also do prefer to always put them into the FROM clause

Comment: @S-Man, I just updated my question with a few more similar queries which are surprisingly working. Can you help me out in understanding the difference? And Thanks for the info on what SELECT list accepts. Didn't know that before.

Comment: It really depends on your data. Please add some minimized data to the question! Maybe you could create a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=25bd3ff2ee3aadfd38487eb7e233bca0

Comment: @S-Man, I tried to reproduce the same thing in that fiddle link but the query is working perfectly fine. Not sure why the error is occurring in our db. You can have a look at the fiddle to see everything I did

Comment: You need to send me the link of your changed fiddle. Every change creates a new URL

Comment: My bad. Even I lost the earlier one. You can find it in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5vvpPQRAxG9yBdAFBxHvb4/3